# Android how to handle data flow in UI

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an `Activity A`

User clicks on a button in Activity A, it starts `Activity B` in **library**

The user interacts with Activity B in **library** and on clicking a Linkedin login button in it,

how to pass control to Activity A so it can do the login related logic and then return to Activity B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that.. Activity A -> Activity B, then click Login -> Activity A..

all you need to do is.. use LinkedIn Callback method after registration. inside that method, Intent to Activity A..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the library is, but I presume that it should return some result. Try with `startActivityForResult` method inside `Activity A`.

For more details please read [Getting result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)